# What's the best way to switch images on mouse-over events?

Tags: jquery, html, css

What's the best way to switch images on mouse-over events ?

I want to swap 2 images when I move the mouse over and out an object on my webpage.

I would like to know for both cases:
   - css-background images assigned to , ,  elements (image url is in css file)
   -  elements (image url is in html code)

I'm currently using jQuery for it. But the problem is that the second image is always showed with a bit of delay the first time a roll-over event occurs, because it needs to be loaded.

NB. I need a solution compatible with all browsers! (IE 6-7 not required. IE 8, Firefox, Safari, Chrome...)

thanks

Comment: Seems to me a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677249/javascript-hover-image-replacement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use [CSS sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).**

Because "both" images are downloads at once - they will appear instantly for the user.

Comment: @m.edmondson All right, anyway are you going to use jQuery to make the roll-over work with all browsers ?

Comment: Why JS, when CSS :hover can do it (bg-image case).

Comment: @bazmegakapa :hover is only working on <a> in internet explorer

Comment: No need to use JQuery - use CSS

Comment: @m.edmondson if you say so, how to detect mouseover events, over <img> elements in internet explorer then ?

Comment: @m.edmondson this posts doesn't specifically mention the <img> mouse-over events, or am I wrong ?

Comment: @Patrick: yes, in IE6, which you said is not required. From IE7, IE has no problems with :hover. Check: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**CSS sprite**](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) in this situation.

You can also read [**What are the advantages of using CSS sprites?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191961/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-css-sprites-in-web-applications)

Answer (score 0):

Define two class like (clsImg1,clsImg2) and define images to their backgrounds.
You should change the classNames while mouseover-mouseout events called

Answer (score 0):

You can try to load the image with jQuery before showing this way:

```
$('img').attr('src', 'YOUR_IMAGE_PATH').hide().appendTo('html');
```

Comment: You have a script here to preload images: http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/12/preloading-images-jquery-and-javascript